# Sequelize one to Many insertion is not working?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

This is my code :

```
         const add_ticket = await db.Ticket.create({ 
              userId,
              travels: ticket.travels,
              TicketInventory: {
                fare: "Fare",
                passenger: "passenger",
                seatName: "seatName",
                serviceTax: "serviceTax",
              }
            },
            {
              include: {
                model: db.TicketInventory,
              }})
```

I need to add "TicketInventory" details under "TicketInventory" table ! But it isnt adding - but rest of the details are been added to "ticket" table !

Association : Ticket HasMany TicketInventory and TicketInventory BelongsTo Ticket !

My assocaition code:

```
/// For Ticket Model
    static associate(models) {
      Ticket.hasMany(models.TicketInventory, { 
        foreignKey: 'ticketId', 
        onDelete: 'CASCADE' ,
        as: 'vegetables'
      });
    }
  };

/// For TicketInventory Model

static associate(models) {
      TicketInventory.belongsTo(models.Ticket, { 
        foreignKey: 'ticketId', 
      });
    }

Please help to resolve
```

Comment: Show association definitions as is

Comment: I have added the association code - pls check @Anatoly

Comment: as: 'vegetables' ??

Comment: LoL, i was just naming it with frustration !

Comment: Then you should indicate an alias in `include` option and change `TicketInventory:` to `vegetables:` and turn a value into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing...

```
const add_ticket = await db.Ticket.create({ 
              userId,
              travels: ticket.travels,
              vegetables: [{
                fare: "Fare",
                passenger: "passenger",
                seatName: "seatName",
                serviceTax: "serviceTax",
              }]
            },
            {
              include: [{
                model: db.TicketInventory,
                as: "vegetables"
              }]
            })
```